# Is there a way to paralelize the use of GPU in Pytorch?

Tags: python, multithreading, time, pytorch, gpu

I have been classifing images with a resnet-18 model in Pytorch, but I want to paralelize it, the problem is that the code is not improving in terms of time:

In the first scenario I tried a classifier with a batch of 64 tensors with the dimensions of ImageNet images:

```
import torch
K = 64
start_time = time.time()
resnet18(torch.rand(2*K,3,224,224).to('cuda'))
print(f'Elapsed time: {time.time()-start_time} seconds')

>>> Elapsed time: 0.18767714500427246 seconds
```

In the second scenario I tried the same classifier with two threads, each one classifing 64 tensors:

```
import threading
import time

def thread_function(batch):
    resnet18(batch)

K = 64
tensors_list = [torch.rand(2*K,3,224,224).to('cuda'), torch.rand(2*K,3,224,224).to('cuda')]

start_time = time.time()
threads = list()
for batch in tensors_list:
    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(batch,))
    threads.append(x)
    x.start()

for index, thread in enumerate(threads):
    thread.join()
print(f'Elapsed time: {time.time()-start_time} seconds')

>>> Elapsed time: 0.3717072010040283 seconds
```

I was expecting that, in both cases the execution time would be the same, but: time(first_scenario) = 2*time(second_scenario).

How can I improve the execution time in this case? Is it possible to improve the execution time using threads?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: is "https://www.run.ai/guides/multi-gpu/pytorch-multi-gpu-4-techniques-explained/" link solve your problem ?

Comment: I think you mean time first scenario is half the time of the second scenario (not double). Pytorch GPU operations are asynchronous so your timing is likely invalid anyway. Take a look at the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html?highlight=asynchronous%20execution#asynchronous-execution) to understand how this works and how to properly time your code.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. When I wrote "but..." I was refering to what actually happened.